# changes data after scrolling in multi recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using multi recycle view in my app . I need to calculate sum of all content in recycle view. But when I am scrolling the value is changing what can be possible error. I have implemented update() method in activity and I am calling in onbindView. So please help me

Comment: show some code. I bet you are counting childrens of `RecyclerView` instead of `getCount` from adapter attached to `RecyclerView`

Comment: No I am calling getCount from adapter only

Comment: show your code, without any piece all is guessing